# CSS partial iteration

Tags: css, animation, iteration

I was thinking about making an animation where, for example, a circle is falling from the top of the screen/website to the bottom and then it starts to rotate without end. I have the idea but I don't know how to describe it in CSS.

This is what I have done so far and get stuck:

```
#circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;

#circle {
    animation-name: falling;
    animation-duration: 5s;

@keyframes falling {
    0% { 
    bottom: 100%; 
}

    50% {
    bottom:0%;
}

    100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

I have no idea how I can make an iteration in the "100%" step. Please give me some advice

Answer (score 4):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/H5HdW/2/)

You can chain animations in CSS by listing their settings in sequence after the relevant CSS animation properties.

Crucially you want to set the animation order, and their respective durations:

`animation: falling 1s, rotate 2s;`

Then queue them to start sequentially:

`animation-delay: 0s, 1s;`

So..the above basically says that the falling animation will last 1 second, play it immediately... then play the rotating animation after 1 second (when falling has finished)

It is also important to specify only playing the falling animation once, but loop the rotation:

`animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;`

Importantly, dont reset the falling animation state on completion...so the circle stays at the bottom of the page, for the rotation..keep it cyclical:

`animation-fill-mode: forwards, both;`

HTML

```
<div id='circle'></div>
```

CSS

```
#circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: auto;
    position:absolute;
    animation: falling 1s, rotate 2s;
    animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards, both;
    -webkit-animation: falling 1s, rotate 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards, both;
}
@keyframes falling {
    0% {
        bottom: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        bottom:0%;
    }
}
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes falling {
    0% {
        bottom: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        bottom:0%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    }
}
```